# Kustomize patch doesn't seem to be following the index order for the container resource

Tags: kubernetes, patch, kustomize

I'm trying to patch/override (remove) a container that is present in base from the overlay.
As per the examples shown in the documentation: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/ the resources follow the order (0 indexed), but that seems to not be working.

base deployment. yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app_name
  labels:
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: container1
          image: "image-1"

        - name: container2
          image: "image-2"  

        - name: container3
          image: "image-3"
```

from the overlay Kustomization.yaml I want to ensure I remove `container2`. Ideally the path should be `/spec/template/spec/containers/1`

```
patches:
  # Disable/Remove container-2 sidecar container from deployment
  - patch: |-
      - op: remove
        path: /spec/template/spec/containers/1
    target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: app_name
```

but it seems to working with the path `/spec/template/spec/containers/2` ie

```
patches:
  # Disable/Remove container-2 sidecar container from deployment
  - patch: |-
      - op: remove
        path: /spec/template/spec/containers/2
    target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: app_name
```

Any reason why it can happen? I validated this several times. (also tried changing the position of container2 specs with container3)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I run the 1st example, `container2` is removed. If I run the 2nd example, `container3` is removed.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for taking a look. Looks like the order of patching matters during merge strategy. Added my solution below that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the order of patching matters. I was able to reproduce the expected behaviour when I patched the containers in kustomization.yaml inline in the order of the deployment.yaml

```
patches:
 - patch: |-
   # patch container 1

  # Disable/Remove container-2 sidecar(indexed 1) container from deployment
  - patch: |-
      - op: remove
        path: /spec/template/spec/containers/1
    target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: app_name

 - patch: |-
   # patch container 3
```

Previously here's the order I was patching => container3, container1 and then container2 . Hence, with the default merge strategy, the container was indexed at 2 or the 3rd position